# SortFields.Clear Clarification

Tags: excel, vba

If this is my only sort statement in my sub then can I just delete SortFields.Clear?
Any useful applications of using SortFields.Clear?

I don't think I have any existing sort fields at the start of my code. Or in the actual worksheet.

Code in question

```
    With ws_raw.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("L2"), Order:=xlDescending
            .SetRange rng_raw
            .Header = xlYes
            .Apply
    End With
```

What I am trying to accomplish, looking for a similar code:

```
    With ws_raw.Sort
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("L2"), Order:=xlDescending
            .SetRange rng_raw
            .Header = xlYes
            .Apply
    End With

    ' main code

    With ws_raw.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .Header = xlYes
            .Apply
    End With
```

Comment: SortFields.Clear clears out previous sort key information. If you don't leave  SortFields.Clear, you will continue to add sort key conditions. So, the first time through, you'll have two sort keys, the second time through, you'll have four. So, every time you run your macro, you'll be adding more keys. To see this, run your macro, select the same range as the macro on the sheet and click Sort in the ribbon. You'll see your keys there. Comment out the  SortFields.Clear and run the macro again. Check the Sort in the sheet again and you'll see the additional sort keys.

Comment: @REXXman thank you.